# AngularJS way of specifying that one controller depends on another

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scenario where I have a parent controller and multiple child controllers that can exist on a page based on some business logic.

The controllers are specified on elements in the dom, and the child controllers are on elements that are controlled by ngSwitch.

e.g. Here is a rather contrived example of what I'm doing.

Parent Controller

```
app.controller('parentCntrl',function($scope){
        $scope.model = {};
        $scope.model.foo = 42;
        //More stuff
});
```

Child Controller

```
app.controller('childCntrl',function($scope){
     $scope.model.bar = 24;
     $scope.myFunction = function() {
        return "The answer is: " + $scope.model.foo;
     };
});
```

As you can see, the child controller depends on the `$scope.model` object to already exist and relies on traversing up the prototype chain to find it.

Is there a way to specify on the child controllers that they require a particular parent controller in order for them to work? My child controllers need to look at properties on the parent scope. Or should I be following some sort of other best practice?

Thanks

Comment: if we are talking about model while defining controllers(parent, child) on DOM level that's fine. but when the point is about code, for such thing you have to use  `shared factory,or service` and pass it `as dependency` for both controller. `keep there all shared data`. and you will be OK.

Comment: I think somebody answered already.. but services are the best practice for sharing data between controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it is to relay on an external to both controllers service, which can allow you to communicate effectively between those controllers, and where your `$scope.model` can be kept nicely and safely.

For example:

```
yourapp.factory('myextprovider', function(){
  // Your code where to updare the $scope.model
})

yourapp.controller('parentctrl', function(myextprovider, $scope){
  $scope.model = myextprovider.somemethods
})
yourapp.controller('childctrl', function(myextprovider, $scope){
  $scope.model = myextprovider.othermethods
})
```

Another way is, depending on the case to use directives, where you can effectively require an external parent directive for the child one, and share the scopes.

I hope I give you an idea of how to proceed in cases like them.